# Problema de ingreso al Git Extensions

Tags: git

Amigos ojalá puedan ayudarme, estuve trabajando con normalidad y de pronto al abrir el git, me muestra el siguiente error `'.', valor hexadecimal 0x1A, es un carácter no válido. Línea 1, posición 1.` y no se como solucionarlo, ya lo desinstale y volví a instalar y aún así persiste el problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola el problema es una mala escritura en el archivo de configuración.

1. Intenta probar de nuevo con la desistalación,
2. Luego borra la siguiente carpeta. `C:\Users\TU_USUARIO\AppData\Roaming\GitExtensions\GitExtensions\`
3. Vuelve a Instalar

Reemplazas `TU_USUARIO` por el que estas usando, solución tomada de incidencias desde el github del proyecto [github.com/gitextensions/issue/2933](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/2933#issuecomment-155184361)

Nota: Esto eliminara tus configuraciones pero las puedes volver a agregar con `git config --global` mas instrucción de configuración de git en [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Empezando-Configurando-Git-por-primera-vez)

Comment: Hola Diego gracias por responder, al desinstalar el GIT me salen 2 opciones

Git Extensions 2.51.02
GitVersion  2.17.0

Sólo desinstalo la primera o las 2 ??

Comment: Lo mejor seria borrar todo para no tener problemas de registro, pero si desea prueba solo con desinstalar la que presenta problemas osea Git Extensions,  y comentas si se pudo solucionar.

Comment: se solucionó mi problema, desinstalé la aplicación, y al volver a instarlo por default se instala en un usuario general, lo cuál me salía para seleccionar mi usuarios el que estoy usando, instaló y todo está ok, muchas gracias por el apoyo.